# How to add a timer to a tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I build a tic tac toe game, and I need to add a timer so if a player does not make a move for 30 sec he loses the game, but I don't know how to implement this in the game.
the game language is Hebrew but it doesn't matter, I try to add a timer from some codes I found on the web with setTimeout but I don't understand how to set the timer to reset after each turn and end the game after the time run and print the other opponent won.
thanks for the help!

```js
const ALL_WIN_COMBINATION = [
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [6, 4, 2],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
];
//Player 'X' plays first
let xTurn = true;
let count = 0;

//Disable All Buttons
const disableButtons = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".block").forEach((element) => (element.disabled = true));
  //enable popup
  document.querySelector(".message").classList.remove("hide");
};

//Enable all buttons (For New Game and Restart)
const enableButtons = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".block").forEach((element) => {
    element.innerText = "";
    element.disabled = false;
  });
  //disable popup
  document.querySelector(".message").classList.add("hide");
};

//This function is executed when a player wins
const winFunction = (letter) => {
  disableButtons();
  if (letter == "X") {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "&#x1F389; <br> 'X' Wins";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "&#x1F389; <br> 'O' Wins";
  }
};

//Function for draw
const drawFunction = () => {
  disableButtons();
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "&#x1F60E; <br> It's a Draw";
};

//New Game
document.getElementById("restart_button2").addEventListener("click", () => {
  count = 0;
  enableButtons();
});
document.getElementById("restart_button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  count = 0;
  enableButtons();
});

//Win Logic
const winChecker = () => {
  //Loop through all win patterns
  for (let i of ALL_WIN_COMBINATION) {
    let [element1, element2, element3] = [
      document.querySelectorAll(".block")[i[0]].innerText,
      document.querySelectorAll(".block")[i[1]].innerText,
      document.querySelectorAll(".block")[i[2]].innerText,
    ];
    //Check if elements are filled
    //If 3 empty elements are same and would give win as would
    if (element1 != "" && (element2 != "") & (element3 != "")) {
      if (element1 == element2 && element2 == element3) {
        //If all 3 buttons have same values then pass the value to winFunction
        winFunction(element1);
      }
    }
  }
};

//Display X/O on click
document.querySelectorAll(".block").forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (xTurn) {
      xTurn = false;
      //Display X
      element.innerText = "X";
      element.disabled = true;
    } else {
      xTurn = true;
      //Display Y
      element.innerText = "O";
      element.disabled = true;
    }
    //Increment count on each click
    count += 1;
    if (count == 9) {
      drawFunction();
    }
    //Check for win on every click
    winChecker();
  });
});
//Enable Buttons and disable popup on page load
window.onload = enableButtons;
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;   
  }
  body {
    height: 70vh;
    background-image: red;
  }
  html {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #intro{
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 2px white,
    11px 1px 2px white,
    1px -1px 0px white,
    -1px -1px 0px white;
  }
  #case {
    position:absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -16%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  #game_board {
    width: 49vmin;
    height: 49vmin;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .block {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 15vmin;
    width: 15vmin;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 14vmin;
    color: black;
  }
  #restart_button {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 90px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
  }
  .message {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    gap: 1em;
    font-size: 12vmin;
  }
  #restart_button2 {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 1em;
        border-radius: 90px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #ffffff;
        position: relative;
  } 
  #text {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 2px white,
    11px 1px 2px white,
    1px -1px 0px white,
    -1px -1px 0px white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  .message.hide {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">
<head>
    <meta charset="UFT-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>איקס עיגול - מאור ישראלי</title>
    <div id="intro">
        <div id = "title">
            <u><h1>איקס עיגול</h1></u>
        </div>
        <div id ="target_header">
            <h2>מטרת המשחק:</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="target">
            <b>מטרת כל שחקן היא ליצור שלושה סימנים (איקס או עיגול) הנמצאים על שורה אחת, טור אחד או אלכסון אחד.</b>
        </div>
        <div id ="instruction_header">
            <h2>הוראות:</h2>
        </div>
        <div id ="instruction">
            <b>
                המשחק מתחיל בלחיצה על אחד התאים,<br>
                השחקן הראשון שלוחץ הוא ה-X והשחקן השני הוא ה-O.<br>
                אם לא מתבצע מהלך תוך 30 שניות השחקן מפסיד!<br>
            </b>
        </div>
        <div id="timer">
            <b><u>
                זמן שנותר: <span id="counter"></span>
            </u></b>
        </div>
    </div>
</head>
<body>
    </div>
    <div id ="case">
        <div id="game_board">
            <button class="block"></button>
            <button class="block"></button>
            <button class="block"></button>
            <button class="block"></button>
            <button class="block"></button>
            <button class="block"></button>
            <button class="block"></button>
            <button class="block"></button>
            <button class="block"></button>
        </div>
        <button id="restart_button">התחל מחדש</button>
    </div>
    <div class="message hide">
        <p id="text">דוגמא</p>
        <button id="restart_button2">התחל מחדש</button>
    </div>
    <script src="tictac.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to set the timeout on each players turn and `clearTimeout` to cancel the previous timeout when each turn starts.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at using a timer strategy in a very basic two players game.

The approach used in this demo is to call `setTimeout` any time the game is waiting for the player to make its move. When the time will be expired, the callback will run closing the game. If the player makes its move before the time expired, the timer gets cleared and a new one initiated for next player.

I did my best to keep it as simple as possible but yet it got more dense in the end when I added a global timer detached from the individual timers belonging to each player single turn. Anyway it further shows how a global timer can be independent by the event timer of players and with smaller time granularity to increment a clock like I did here:

```js
document.getElementById('makemove')
  .addEventListener('click', waitForNextMove);
  
function waitForNextMove(){
  resetTimer();

  currentPlayer = ++currentPlayer % 2;  
  playerName = players[currentPlayer];
  console.log(`${playerName}, waiting for your next move...`);
  document.querySelector('.player').innerText = playerName;
  //here resets the previous timer
  clearInterval(currentTimer);
  //and starts the new one
  currentTimer = setTimeout(onTimeExpired, duration);
}

const onTimeExpired = () => {
  console.log("Time expired!");
  gameOver();
  
  stopTimer();
}

const gameOver = () => {
  console.log('The game is over.');
  document.getElementById('makemove').disabled = true;
}

const duration = 5000;
const players = ['player1', 'player2'];
let currentPlayer = -1;
let currentTimer;
let globalTimer;

waitForNextMove();

//----Global Timer
startTimer();

function startTimer(){
  globalTimer =
    setInterval(()=>{
      incrementTimer();
    }, 1000);
}
function stopTimer(){
  document.getElementById('timer').innerText = '5';
  clearInterval(globalTimer);
}
function resetTimer(){
  document.getElementById('timer').innerText = '0';
}
function incrementTimer(){
  const t = document.getElementById('timer');
  const i = parseInt(t.innerText) + 1;
  t.innerText = i;
}
```

```css
:root{
  --padding: .2rem .6rem;
}

label{
  border: solid lightgray;
  padding: var(--padding);
}

button{
  padding: var(--padding);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#timer{
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 2px;
  padding: var(--padding);
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<label>PLAYER: <span class="player"></span></label>
<button id="makemove">Make your move!</button>

<div id="timer">1</div>
```